# Sharepoint Data source within SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a query which is written in SQL Server and this gives me what I require.

I have a new requirement to add a Sharepoint Data source field on to the same SQL Query and perform some matching against them.

I know how to add a Sharepoint source as a Datasource within SSRS, however not quite sure how this can be implemented within SQL itself?

Note: my front end for the SQL query is SSRS i.e. once all sorted on SQL, I copy across to SSRS and design accordingly.

Comment: Are you asking how to join to a Sharepoint field within your SQL?

Comment: Yes, is it possible?

Comment: It is possible **but** do you know the fields and values to join on?

Comment: Yes I do... their are 2 unique fields which are same on both side i.e. on Sql Side db & on Sharepoint